# unable to get the update location using gps provider and network provider?

Tags: android, gps

Hi am trying get GPS using network provider and GPS provider. but am getting the same value.the value is not updated.ie my onlocation value is noy updated.

```
   private Location networkLoc;
   private Location gpsLoc;
   private static double lat;
   private static  TextView latituteField1;
   private static TextView longitudeField1; 
   private static double lng ;
   private static double  lat1;
   private static double lng1 ;
   provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
   networkLoc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
   gpsLoc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

 if (networkLoc != null) {
System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
  lat1 = (double) (networkLoc.getLatitude());
 lng1 = (double) (networkLoc.getLongitude());
latituteField.setText(Double.toString(lat1));
longitudeField.setText(Double.toString(lng1));
  } 
  if ( gpsLoc  != null) {
System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
     lat = (double) (gpsLoc.getLatitude());
 lng = (double) (gpsLoc.getLongitude());
latituteField1.setText(Double.toString(lat));
longitudeField1.setText(Double.toString(lng));

     }
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
  lat1 = (double) (networkLoc.getLatitude());
     lng1 = (double) (networkLoc.getLongitude());
    latituteField.setText(Double.toString(lat1));//these two values are same
    longitudeField.setText(Double.toString(lng1));      
    lat = (double) (gpsLoc.getLatitude());
     lng = (double) (gpsLoc.getLongitude());
    latituteField1.setText(Double.toString(lat));//these two values are same
    longitudeField1.setText(Double.toString(lng));              
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a good look at this blog post: [A Deep Dive Into Location](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html).  It will provide you with a number of best practices.  Calling `getLastKnownLocation` is not going to start the location providers.  You should use requestLocationUpdates.  See snippet below:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

Criteria fineCriteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
String fineProvider = lm.getBestProvider(fineCriteria, true);

// Start the fine location listener
lm.requestLocationUpdates(fineProvider, 0, 0, locationListenerFine);

private LocationListener locationListenerFine = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
};
```

Comment: Make sure you have GPS and Network location enabled.  In the example above fineProvider should be "GPS_PROVIDER".  With GPS you only get updates if you have a fix.  A fix can take several minutes.